# The identifier that starts with 'x' is too long (SQL)

Tags: java, sql

I'm passing a date into a SQL query (which works in other code I have) but for some reason isn't playing nicely here. I'll post the code below.

```
 Calendar limitDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        limitDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        limitDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        limitDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        limitDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        //remove records 221 days old or older
        limitDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -221);
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(limitDate.getTimeInMillis());
        int deleteCnt = 0;
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();

        StringBuilder wgpSql = new StringBuilder("select wgpapt.* ");
        wgpSql.append("from THB_View.WGPAPT wgpapt ");
        wgpSql.append("left outer join THB_View.WGP wgp on wgpapt.WGP_TAG = wgp.WGP_TAG ");
        wgpSql.append("where wgpapt.CREATE_DATE <= '" + sqlDate + "' ");
        wgpSql.append("and wgp.RECORD_KEY is null");
        List<Object[]> sqlResultSet = ExecuteSql.executeNativeSqlString(wgpSql.toString(), null);
```

The error I get in the console is: The identifier that starts with 'Ljava.lang.Object;@4906038d,[Ljava.lang.Object;@366cabed,[Ljava.lang.Object;@651d74a9,[Ljava.lang.Object;@354aea35,[Ljava.lang.O' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

edit: my complete code is below

```
package com.yrc.mcc.app.batch;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.yrc.mcc.core.core.MccMidusException;
import com.yrc.mcc.core.file.MList;
import com.yrc.mcc.core.program.BatchProgram;
import com.yrc.mcc.core.sql.ExecuteSql;
import com.yrc.mcc.data.file.Wgpapt;


@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class BShp830 extends BatchProgram {

    public int deleteRecords(Map<String, List<String>> recordKeys) {
        MList<Wgpapt> delList = new MList<>();
        delList.populateFromTypeMap(Wgpapt.class, recordKeys);
        for (Wgpapt record : delList) {
            record.delete();
        }
        recordKeys.get("").clear();
        int result = 0;

        try {
            this.commit();
            print("Succesfully deleted " + delList.size() + " records");
            result = delList.size();
            // Do we want a delay here?
        } catch (MccMidusException mme) {
            if ("0080".equals(mme.getErrorCode())) {
                this.getIoHarness().pokeUow(mme.getUow());
                // Call commit to get a new transaction started.
                this.commit();
                // Reset the counter.
            } else {
                throw mme;
            }
        }
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
        // Find the first 5,000 records to remove.
        Calendar limitDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        limitDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        limitDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        limitDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        limitDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        //remove records 221 days old or older
        limitDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -221);
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(limitDate.getTimeInMillis());
        int deleteCnt = 0;
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();

        StringBuilder wgpSql = new StringBuilder("select wgpapt.* ");
        wgpSql.append("from THB_View.WGPAPT wgpapt ");
        wgpSql.append("left outer join THB_View.WGP wgp on wgpapt.WGP_TAG = wgp.WGP_TAG ");
        wgpSql.append("where wgpapt.CREATE_DATE <= '" + sqlDate.toString() + "' ");
        wgpSql.append("and wgp.RECORD_KEY is null");
        List<Object[]> sqlResultSet = ExecuteSql.executeNativeSqlString(wgpSql.toString(), null);

        int i = 0;
        Map<String, List<String>> recordKeys = new HashMap<>();
        recordKeys.put("", new ArrayList<String>());

        for (Object value : sqlResultSet) {
            recordKeys.get("").add(value.toString());
            i++;
            if (i == 100) {
                deleteRecords(recordKeys);
                deleteCnt += i;
                print("Running delete count is: " + deleteCnt);
                i = 0;
            }
        }

        if (i != 0) {
            // Ensure anything else gets committed.
            deleteRecords(recordKeys);
            deleteCnt += i;
        }
        print("** P R O C E D U R E  S H P 8 3 0", false);
        print("** DELETING RECORDS WITH A CREATE DATE ", false);
        print("** PRIOR TO " + limitDate.getTime().toString(), false);
        print("** TOTAL WGPAPT RECORDS DELETED = " + deleteCnt, false);
        print("*****************************************", false);
        print("** PROCEDURE SHP830 COMPLETED * ", false);
        print("** AT: " + formatter.format(date) + " *", false);
        print(" ", false);

        this.webDone();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to stringify objects that don't have `toString` overloaded. Those look like arrays of Objects, or Longs.

Comment: Nothing in your example could cause it, post related code and exception.

Comment: what is the value of sqlDate looks like in the append, the formatter has not been applied seems like?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli [`java.sql.Date.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--) always return in format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: I will edit my post and include my complete code

Comment: I posted my complete code below my original post in an edit. My compiler says the program blows up on line 28, which for me is `delList.populateFromTypeMap(Wgpapt.class, recordKeys);`

Comment: Do not pass date values as strings or even worse: concatenate them into a SQL string. Use a `PreparedStatement` and use pass instances of `LocalDateTime` or at least `java.sql.Timestamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. My SQL statement says `("select wgpapt.* ");` which takes the entire result rather than the record key sequence I was trying to obtain. This was far too long and causing my code to error out.

the solution was to change my select statement to

```
("select wgpapt.RECORD_KEY ");
```

Comment: The error suggests that your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection (and it is), you should really learn how to properly use prepared statements with parameters instead of concatenating values into query strings.

Comment: Sadly I don't get to make that design decision, but I do understand the vulnerability in this case